# Word for "Put them apart from each other" (for humans)?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a synonym for *"put them apart from each other"* when referring to people?

Here's an example:

> My child is sitting next to a troublemaker in the class. I want to tell his teacher to *put them apart from each other*.

What is the most suitable word for such a scenario?

Comment: Move them apart? That's the simplest way I can think of, I don't know whether there's a shorter way.

Comment: ***Separate*** them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for *separate*:

> to set or keep apart

<sub>source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separate)</sub>

It can be used for both objects and people. Your example would become:

> My child is sitting next to a troublemaker in the class. I want to tell his teacher to *separate them*.

Comment: I have to say, _separate_ was floating inside my head all the time, but I thought there would a better word for such. Thanks for confirming it. **EDIT**: Just for the sake of clarity; I upvoted you but seems "newbies" have their voting hidden from the public eyes ;)

Comment: Do note that it's sep**a**rate - this is one of the most commonly misspelled words in English.